# pgfplots: positioning a normal and tangent vector on a 3d surface

Tags: pgfplots

I feel that there should be a simple, good way to plot a 3d surface and place a vector (or more) at one point on it, where the vector is a function of the point and the surface. For example, a normal vector.

I can of course compute the corrdinates and input those as a `draw`, but that doesn't seem to be the efficient way to do it. I'm looking for something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
]
\begin{axis}[
xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
domain=0:2,
domain y=-1.3:1.3,
]
\addplot3[
surf,
shader=interp,
] 
{exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};
\addplot3[
black,-stealth,samples=2,
quiver,quiver/.cd,
    u=-exp(-x^2-y^2)+2*exp(-x^2-y^2)*x^2,v=2*exp(-x^2-y^2)*x*y,w=1,
    scale arrows=0.2,
] {exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};
\addplot3[
blue,-stealth,samples=2,
quiver,quiver/.cd,
    u=2*exp(-x^2-y^2)*x*y,v=exp(-x^2-y^2)-2*exp(-x^2-y^2)*x^2,w=0,
    scale arrows=5.8,
] {exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Only I want to control the exact points at which the vectors are placed (say, `x=1` and `y=0`, and have `pgfplots` compute the corresponding `z` coordinate and the vector etc.).

Comment: Could you perhaps explain why you think your quivers will provide the tangents and normals? Superficially at least the top left combination does not really seem to display a tangent and normal. And it is always a good idea to promote the code to a full MWE, i.e. something that starts with `\dcoumentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @marmot Thank you for the suggestion, done. Regarding the math, I think it's fine but regardless, say I want whatever vector my formula yields (that depends on the point etc.). How would I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I can do is to tell you how you can draw single quiver arrows at a predefined position. This can be done using a table. However, I am not convinced that these are tangents and normals of the surface. Apart from the fact that a two-dimensional surface has a two-dimensional tangent space (meaning that there is not a single tangent), the information of the value of the function is missing. To me the output of the below code is just the two tangents at the curves defined by `x=0` or `y=0`, respectively, but attached at `z=0` rather than `z=f(x,y)`. (It might well be that I introduced a sign error. I will be happy to expand this further. IMHO there are two well-defined arrow-like objects that one could plot: gradient and normal. Are you secretly looking for those?) It also makes sense to use `declare function` if one is to deal with lengthy expressions that one wants to use multiple times.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x,\y)=exp(-\x*\x-\y*\y)*\x;
dfdx(\x,\y)=exp(-\x*\x-\y*\y)-2*exp(-\x*\x-\y*\y)*\x^2;
dfdy(\x,\y)=-2*exp(-\x*\x-\y*\y)*\x*\y;}]
\begin{axis}[
xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
domain=0:2,
domain y=-1.3:1.3,
]
\addplot3[
surf,
shader=interp,
] 
{f(x,y)};

\addplot3 [color=blue,-stealth,
    quiver={u={-dfdx(\thisrow{x},\thisrow{y})},v={-dfdy(\thisrow{x},\thisrow{y})},
    w=1,scale arrows=0.2},
    ] table {
x y z
1 0 0
0.7 0.2 0
    };

\addplot3 [color=blue,-stealth,
    quiver={u={-dfdy(\thisrow{x},\thisrow{y})},v={dfdx(\thisrow{x},\thisrow{y})},
    w=0,scale arrows=2},
    ] table {
x y z
1 0 0
0.7 0.2 0
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As for the question in the comment: you can add the `z` coordinate. One possibility is

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x,\y)=exp(-\x*\x-\y*\y)*\x;
dfdx(\x,\y)=exp(-\x*\x-\y*\y)-2*exp(-\x*\x-\y*\y)*\x^2;
dfdy(\x,\y)=-2*exp(-\x*\x-\y*\y)*\x*\y;}]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\fone}{f(1,0)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ftwo}{f(0.7,0.2)}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
domain=0:2,
domain y=-1.3:1.3,
]
\addplot3[
surf,
shader=interp,
] 
{f(x,y)};

\addplot3 [color=blue,-stealth,
    quiver={u={-dfdx(\thisrow{x},\thisrow{y})},v={-dfdy(\thisrow{x},\thisrow{y})},
    w=1,scale arrows=0.2}, % ,z={f(\thisrow{x},\thisrow{y})}
    ] table {
x y z
1 0 \fone
0.7 0.2 \ftwo
    };

\addplot3 [color=blue,-stealth,
    quiver={u={-dfdy(\thisrow{x},\thisrow{y})},v={dfdx(\thisrow{x},\thisrow{y})},
    w=0,scale arrows=2},
    ] table {
x y z
1 0 \fone
0.7 0.2 \ftwo
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I guess that there *must* be a simpler way to add the `z` coordinate. But I am still not sure that I know what I am doing here. I would be much more enthusiastic if I knew what you really want to plot. One *can* draw tangents of parametric curves in `x` and `y` directions, and their vector product yields the normal. So far, we add `w` by hand, but we could just calculate it, can't one?

Comment: Looks great. Is there a way that I can control the base point of the vectors in a way that depends on x, y and z (say, place them at the height of the surface)?

Comment: @YMA I added a possible way plus some comment what I would do to compute the tangents (plural) and normal vector.

Comment: Better. Regarding what I want to do: forget the second, tangent vector. Say I'm just looking to plot a normal (specifically, `(-\grad f,1)`). Thanks a lot for the help and patience.