# Drawing a parametric line with unitary director vector produces a longer straight line using PGFPlots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to plot a normal bounded line to a surface in a point.

The surface is `y=x` and the point is `(1/2,1/2,1)`. The gradient is `(-1,1,0)`, and at point `(1/2,1/2,1)` is still the same, thus the normal line would be `(x-1/2)/(-1)=(y-1/2)/(1)=(z-1)/(0)`, hence the line is described by `(.5,.5,1)+t(-1,1,0)`.

However, I want the line to be **bounded**, in order to make a **unitary director vector**, but I am not able to do these. I am using `t` between `0` and `1`, but these draw a long line; I want it to be a vector of **length `1`**.

I am not sure if this math is correct. If I find the unitary vector of `(-1,1,0)` it is `(-1,1,0)/(sqrt(2))` i.e. `(-sqrt(2)/2,sqrt(2)/2,0)` then I still do not have a vector of length `1` (when `t` is between `0` and `1`).

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis} [
                title={Without normalizing $(-1,1,0)$ ($t\in[0,1]$)},
                axis on top,
                axis lines=center,
                xlabel=$x$,
                ylabel=$y$,
                zlabel=$z$,
                ticklabel style={font=\tiny},
                view={115}{25}
            ]
            \addplot3[opacity=.5,surf,samples=21,variable=\t,variable y=\s,domain=0:2,y domain=0:90,z buffer=sort,colormap={red}{color=(red) color=(red)}] ({\t*cos(\s)*(sqrt(2)*.5)},{\t*cos(\s)*(sqrt(2)*.5)},{\t*sin(\s)});%Red S
            \addplot3[-stealth,variable=\t,domain=0:1] ({1/2+t},{1/2-t},{1});
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \hfill
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis} [
                title={Normalizing $(-1,1,0)$ ($t\in[0,1]$)},
                axis on top,
                axis lines=center,
                xlabel=$x$,
                ylabel=$y$,
                zlabel=$z$,
                ticklabel style={font=\tiny},
                view={115}{25}
            ]
            \addplot3[opacity=.5,surf,samples=21,variable=\t,variable y=\s,domain=0:2,y domain=0:90,z buffer=sort,colormap={red}{color=(red) color=(red)}] ({\t*cos(\s)*(sqrt(2)*.5)},{\t*cos(\s)*(sqrt(2)*.5)},{\t*sin(\s)});%Red S
            \addplot3[-stealth,variable=\t,domain=0:1] ({1/2+(sqrt(2)/2)*t},{1/2-(sqrt(2)/2)*t},{1});
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

**Even the line has a bad quality, it looks pixelated:**

[image: Pixelated line]

**Does anyone know how to produce a vector of length `1` or what am I missing?**

Some links of interest:

- [`pgfplots`: positioning a normal and tangent vector on a 3d surface](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/455024/152550)
- [Find a good view for a function by parts using `tikzpicture` environment [Overleaf]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/456987/152550)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I am not missing anything obvious. You only need to divide by `sqrt(2)` in your left example to arrive at

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis} [
                title={Normalizing},
                axis on top,
                axis lines=center,
                xlabel=$x$,
                ylabel=$y$,
                zlabel=$z$,
                ticklabel style={font=\tiny},
                view={115}{25}
            ]
            \addplot3[opacity=.5,surf,samples=21,variable=\t,variable y=\s,domain=0:2,y domain=0:90,z buffer=sort,colormap={red}{color=(red) color=(red)}] ({\t*cos(\s)*(sqrt(2)*.5)},{\t*cos(\s)*(sqrt(2)*.5)},{\t*sin(\s)});%Red S            
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\msq}{sqrt(1/2)}
            \addplot3[-stealth,variable=\t,samples at={0,\msq},samples y=0] ({1/2+t},{1/2-t},{1});
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The "pixelation" went away after adding `samples y=0`.

Comment: Thanks for the trick of `samples y=0`! I already divided by `sqrt(2)` in the right side, but I use `1/sqrt(2)=sqrt(2)/2` (I rationalized). Use `view{115}{90}` to see the line better, I do not think that the line has length `1` :(.

Comment: @manooooh It has the length 1 in the units used in the plot. These are orthonormal projections so the result of a projection looks shorter than the actual length.

Comment: So I do not get how do you end up with `sqrt(1/2)` instead of `sqrt(2)`, nor I do not know how to interpret "You only need to divide by `sqrt(2)` in your left example". Do you mean that I have to divide each parameter by `sqrt(2)` or only the vector?

Comment: @manooooh We add a vector in the xy-plane. This vector goes in the `(1,-1)` direction. The normalized vector in this direction is `(1/sqrt(2),-1/sqrt(2))=(cos(-45),sin(-45))`.

Comment: That is what I have done. I have used `sqrt(2)/2` instead of `1/sqrt(2)`.

Comment: @manooooh Yes, then that's the correct result. (Sorry, I only looked at the left plot and normalized it. ;-)

Comment: Haha, no problem :). So, how do you go from `({1/2+(sqrt(2)/2)*t},{1/2-(sqrt(2)/2)*t},{1})` to your answer? I do not know why did you use `\pgfmathsetmacro{\msq}{sqrt(1/2)}` instead of `\pgfmathsetmacro{\msq}{sqrt(2)}`.

Comment: @manooooh Because `sqrt(2)` is by a factor 2 too long. ;-)

Comment: LOL! But the norm of `(1,-1,0)` is `sqrt(2)`, not `sqrt(1/2)`!

Comment: @manooooh Yes, but we have to divide by the norm.

Comment: So... it is `1/sqrt(2)` (equals to `sqrt(2)/2`), not `1/sqrt(1/2)`.

Comment: @manooooh Yes, `1/sqrt(2)` and `sqrt(1/2)` are the same.